# Ruby: Get sum of nested hash values

Tags: ruby, hash

I've got a hash of arrays grouped by year, like so:

```
{
    1979 => [
        [0] {
             :x => "12/79",
             :y => 71,
            :date => Sat, 01 Dec 1979
        }
    ],
    1980 => [
        [0] {
            :x => "01/80",
            :y => 1680,
            :date => Tue, 01 Jan 1980
        },
        [1] {
            :x => "08/80",
            :y => 1,
            :date => Fri, 01 Aug 1980
        }
    ]
}
```

I need a way to sum all of the `[:y]` key values by year, and then push the new value into another hash (or collapse the same hash), where I set the value for `:x`.

The output would look something like this:

```
{
  { 
    :x => "1/79",
    :y => 71,
  },
  {
    :x => "1/1980",
    :y => 1681
  }
}
```

Comment: And... what have you tried so far?

Comment: your output should be array of hash. output hash is not valid

Comment: How are the values for :x determined? I do not see a rule here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input hash corrected:

```
foo = {
    1979 => [
        {
             :x => "12/79",
             :y => 71,
            :date => Sat, 01 Dec 1979
        }
    ],
    1980 => [
        {
            :x => "01/80",
            :y => 1680,
            :date => Tue, 01 Jan 1980
        },
        {
            :x => "08/80",
            :y => 1,
            :date => Fri, 01 Aug 1980
        }
    ]
}

bar = foo.collect { |k,v| { :x => "1/#{k.to_s}", :y => v.inject(0) { |s, vv| s + vv[:y]}} }
```

`bar` is:

```
[
  { 
    :x => "1/79",
    :y => 71,
  },
  {
    :x => "1/1980",
    :y => 1681
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?:

```
out = {}
h.each{|key,arr|
  total = arr.inject{|sum,entry|
      sum+=entry[:y]
  } 
  out[key]= {:y=>sum,:x=>"01/#{key}"}
}
```